# Deletion in BST

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I was trying to perform deletion in a binary search tree (BST), but it was giving a segmentation fault after printing the deleted array.

```
treeNode *minVal(treeNode *root)
{
    if(root == NULL || root->left==NULL)
        return root;
    else
        minVal(root->left);
}

treeNode *deleteBST(treeNode *root,int value)
{
    treeNode *tempNode;
    
    if(value>root->value)
        deleteBST(root->right,value);
    else if(value<root->value)
        deleteBST(root->left,value);
    else
    {
        if(root->left==NULL)
        {
            tempNode = root->right;
            free(root);
            return tempNode;
        }
        else if(root->right==NULL)
        {
            tempNode = root->left;
            free(root);
            return tempNode;
        }
        else
        {
            tempNode = minVal(root->right);
            root->value=tempNode->value;
            root->right = deleteBST(root->right,tempNode->value);
        }
    }
    return root;    
}
```

Comment: If `deleteBST` is called with `treeNode *root` being `NULL`, then the first `if` condition would be accessing `root->value`, which is illegal since `root == NULL`.

Comment: Why bother to have `deleteBST()` return a value when the rest of the code doesn't care what that might be, or the reconstructive surgery that may have occurred??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

updated working code is attached with comments to the errors.

```
treeNode *minVal(treeNode *root)
{
    if(root == NULL || root->left==NULL)
        return root;
    else
        return minVal(root->left);//1.returning a value is a must here
}

treeNode *deleteBST(treeNode *root,int value)
{
    treeNode *tempNode;
    if(root==NULL)//2.handling the base case
        return NULL;
    if(value>root->value)
        return deleteBST(root->right,value);
    else if(value<root->value)
        return deleteBST(root->left,value);
    else
    {
        if(root->left==NULL)
        {
            tempNode = root->right;
            free(root);
            return tempNode;
        }
        else if(root->right==NULL)
        {
            tempNode = root->left;
            free(root);
            return tempNode;
        }
        else
        {
            tempNode = minVal(root->right);
            root->value=tempNode->value;
            root->right = deleteBST(root->right,tempNode->value);
            return root;//can be skipped
        }
    }
    return root;    
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify the reason for adding return statement at those points.

Comment: 1st comment return statement is needed because minval function is expected to return a value and 3rd comment return statement is optional.

Comment: This fixes a couple of problems with the OP's code, but it's still pretty far from correct.

Comment: These kinds of code-only answers are not very helpful. You should edit your answer to explain what you changed in OP's code and why

Answer (score -1):

Presumably the point of `deleteBST()` returning a `treeNode *` is that the return value points to the new root of the (sub)tree.  The new root will differ from the original one if the deleted value was found in the original root, so some means of updating the root is required.

That needs to be handled appropriately by this function's callers, including this function itself when it performs recursive calls.  **Your function fails to do this.**

**Your function also fails to properly handle the case when the specified value is not found in the tree.**  It will eventually attempt to dereference a null pointer if such a value is passed.

And **the actual deletion performed by your function is totally inadequate.**  It frees the node where the value is found, but it does not adjust the subtree rooted at that node to have a valid structure, and it leaves the parent of the deleted node with a (then) invalid child pointer.

---

The general scheme for deletion from a BST would be like this:

- if the root, **R**, of the tree is null then return null; otherwise,
- if the value to delete is less than the value of **R**, then
  delete it from the left subtree *and update **R**'s left pointer to point to the new root of the left subtree*; otherwise,
- if the value to delete is greater than the value of **R**, then
  delete it from the right subtree *and update **R**'s right pointer to point to the new root of the right subtree*; otherwise,
- the value to delete is the value of **R** itself.  In this case,

  1. Select a new root for this subtree:

     - if both **R**'s children are null then the new root is also null.
     - if exactly one child is null then the other is the new root.
     - if neither child is null then you can choose either the smallest node in the right subtree or the largest one in the left subtree.  These are **R**'s immediate in-order successor and predecessor, respectively.
  2. In the case where neither of **R**'s children is null, update the subtree appropriately. Supposing that the smallest node of the right subtree, **MR**, is the selected new root, you must

     1. remove **MR** from its current parent by updating the parent's pointer to it to point instead at **MR**'s right child (which might or might not be null).  Including when the parent is **R**.
     2. update **MR**'s left and right child pointers to be the same as **R**'s.
  3. Free **R**.
- return the root of the subtree (original or new, as appropriate)